# Parsing Integer from JSON not working

Tags: android, json

I am attempting to make an app in android studio that gets live currency rates, so I decided to use a `JSON` to do this. I am currently able to print out the entire `JSON` as a string, however I would like to be able to set the `TextView` to the USD conversion rate, however it doesn't work. The `TextView` does not change. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
public class Converter extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView txtJson;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_converter);
    txtJson = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvJsonItem);
    new JsonTask().execute("https://openexchangerates.org/api/latest.json?app_id=870447ebb4d94379972250a3bdaed73f");
}
private class JsonTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(params[0]);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.connect();
            InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
            String line = "";
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                buffer.append(line + "\n");
                Log.d("Response: ", "> " + line);   
            }
            return buffer.toString();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (connection != null) {
                connection.disconnect();
            }
            try {
                if (reader != null) {
                    reader.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    public void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        try {
            JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(result);
            int USD = jObject.getInt("USD");
            String strUSD = Integer.toString(USD);
            txtJson.setText(strUSD);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the `"rates"` object before you can access the `"USD"` value

Also, it's not an integer. It's a double

```
getJSONObject("rates").getDouble("USD")
```

Comment: May I add some code to your answer?

Comment: You could keep your own answer.